# Limit with geometric sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I computed
 $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[n]{n^n+n^{n+1}+\cdots+n^{2n}} \cdot\left(1-\cos{\frac{3}{n}}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } n^2 \sqrt[n]{n^{-n}+n^{-n+1}+\cdots+1} \cdot \left(1-\cos \frac{3}{n} \right) $$
$$=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[n]{n^{-n}+n^{-n+1}+ \cdots +1} \cdot \frac{1-\cos \frac{3}{n} }{\frac{9}{n^2}}\cdot 9=\frac{9}{2} $$

1) Is it correct to extract $n^{2n}$ from $\sqrt[n]{n^n+n^{n+1}+\cdots+n^{2n}}$ the way I did?

2)How do I show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[n]{n^{-n}+n^{-n+1}+\cdots+1}=1$?

I came up with this:
for geometric sequence the sum can be computed as $s_n=a_1\frac{q^n-1}{q-1}$, but I learned this in high school and if I recall correctly we used it for finite number of terms. So I don't know if I can use it here as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[n]{n^{-n}+n^{-n+1}+\cdots+1} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[n]{n^{-n}\cdot \frac{n^n-1}{n-1}+1}$$

So I can estimate upper/lower bound:

$$\sqrt[n]{1} \le \sqrt[n]{n^{-n}\cdot \frac{n^n-1}{n-1}+1} \le \sqrt[n]n $$

Then:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \sqrt[n]{n^{-n}+n^{-n+1}+\cdots+1}=1$$

Thank you.

Comment: It's all perfect as it is. Observe that, for any given $n\in\Bbb N$, the geometric series in question has only *finite* members.

Comment: thank you, I was eagerly waiting for someone to tell me his/her thoughts on this. So it is alright this way, I see. I assume same could be applied for the sum of arithmetic sequence?(with different formula of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have these inequalities

$$n^2\le(n^n+\cdots+n^{2n})^{1/n}\le((n+1)n^{2n})^{1/n}=n^2(n+1)^{1/n}\sim_\infty n^2$$
and  by Taylor series
$$1-\cos\left(\frac 3 n\right)\sim_\infty\frac 1 2\left(\frac{3}{ n}\right)^2=\frac{9}{2n^2}$$
hence
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } {\sqrt[n]{n^n+n^{n+1}+...+n^{2n}}\cdot(1-\cos{\frac{3}{n}})}=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }n^2\frac{9}{2n^2}=\frac{9}{2}$$

Comment: I was hoping for more elementary way, as we have not defined Taylor series in our class, but thank you anyway.

Comment: @cryogenic Do you know that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos x}{x^2}=\frac 1 2?$$

Comment: Yes sure, I managed to solve the problem(see the question above), I was just not sure with some parts of it. For exams we are required to not only compute the limits but also provide "explanations" for the steps we make.

Comment: @cryogenic So you have the full answer with elementary way and I'm sure that you know what we should write!

Comment: I was asking for verification and feedback, I specified with what parts I wasn't sure, as it is often possible to get correct answer with wrong "reasoning" behind it...I apologize if I didn't make it clear enough.

Comment: @cryogenic Do you understand the inequalities? If yes I'll edit my answer for elementary way.

Comment: no, I don't think I understand it. Do you think you can show it different way than I did?

Comment: @cryogenic In the sum $n^n+\cdots+n^{2n}$ there's $n+1$ terms and the biggest term is $n^{2n}$. It's clear that this sum is greater than $n^{2n}$ and smaller than $(n+1)n^{2n}$ since each term is small than $n^{2n}$ and we have as I said $n+1$ terms so write these inequalities then pass to the power $1/n$ and simplfy.

Answer (score 1):

Your geometric series has $n$ terms, of which all but the last two are smaller than $1/n^2,$ so their sum is smaller than $1/n,$ so the expression under the radical is smaller than $1+2/n,$ so it goes to $1,$ hence so does its $n$th root.